# How can I create a non-admingroup User that can run Import and Export in HAC successfully?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

For: SAP Commerce 1905.29

How can I create a User that can run Import (Console > ImpEx Import) and Export (Console > ImpEx Export) in HAC successfully? However, I don't want to give them access to destructive functions like Platform Initialize, Platform Update, or suspending threads. So, I don't want to assign them to admingroup.

As an experiment, I created a custom usergroup that is a member of employeegroup. When I created a new Employee and assigned the custom usergroup to it, it can log-in to HAC. But when the user performs FlexSearch, an error is displayed:

```
could not translate value expression 'session.catalogversions'
```

[image]

In HAC, the Import and Export functions causes an error.

In Backoffice, the Import and Export functions (under System > Tools) work properly.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This error coming from search restriction. Search restrictions available by user/usergroup. So you need to add your user group to these restrictions. You can find it in type system with name **SearchRestriction**.
More details are here: https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_COMMERCE/4c33bf189ab9409e84e589295c36d96e/d913a77e22e7442381a2bd57065f1eb6.html?locale=en-US&q=Search%20Restriction

Comment: Thanks for chiming in. After discussing with my colleague, my question is wrong. It seems it's the Import/Export function causing this issue. In HAC, the error occurs. In Backoffice, the error does not occur. I'll update the question.

Comment: You can check restrictions which are included session.catalogversions and disable them for testing.