# Flexible search is asking for session country while called from REST api

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud, flexible-search

I have a code which executes a flexible search. When i am calling that code locally to search data it gives expected output but when I try to call it using REST API (Through controller) it gives error as *could not translate value expression 'session.currentCountry'* but i am not even using session or session country anywhere in flexible search. what can be issue?

here is code

query

```
select {rr.pk} from {returnrequest as rr join order as r on {r.pk} = {rr.order} join orderstatus as os on {r.status}={os.pk} join basestore as bs on {bs.pk}={r.store} join returntype as rt on {rr.returntype} = {rt.pk} join paymentmode as pm on {pm.pk}={r.paymentmode} join returnstatus as rs on {rs.PK}={rr.status}} where {os.code} NOT in ('PENDING_PAYMENT','ON_VALIDATION', 'CREATED', 'IN_PROGRESS', 'ORDER_SPLIT','CANCELLED') and {rr.creationtime} >= ?returnCreationDateFrom and {rr.creationtime} < ?returnCreationDateTo and {bs.uid} in (?market) and {rt.code} in (?returnType) and {pm.code} = 'SplittedPaymentMode' and {rr.totalRefund} != 0.0 and {rs.code}!='RECEIVED' group by {rr.pk} ";
```

code

```
FlexibleSearchQuery query = new FlexibleSearchQuery(flexiQuery.toString());
query.addQueryParameter("market", market);
query.addQueryParameter("returnType", returnType);
query.addQueryParameter("returnCreationDateTo", DateUtils.addDays(returnCreationDateTo, 1));
query.addQueryParameter("returnCreationDateFrom", returnCreationDateFrom);
SearchResult<ReturnRequestModel> results = search(query);
```

same flow is running properly in local but giving issues in remote instace.

here is error

```
ERROR PaymentWsController de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.search.exceptions.FlexibleSearchException: could not translate value expression 'session.currentCountry'
19:37:31.834 [hybrisHTTP6] ERROR de.hybris.platform.jalo.flexiblesearch.FlexibleSearch - Flexible search error occured...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although others answers on the post are correct I just want to add my answer which helped to solve the issue.

The issue was with search restriction.

I just set current user as admin to bypass the restrictions. i.e.

```
userService.setCurrentUser(userService.getAdminUser());
```

I just added it before executing the search and error got resolved.

we can also set user as admin in flexiquery itself so that search restrictions can be avoided.

here is how.

```
query.setUser(userService.getAdminUser());
```

so both ways it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

This error coming from research restriction. It looks your user hasn't got some session variables and a restriction try to use it. You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72967751/how-can-i-create-a-non-admingroup-user-that-can-run-import-and-export-in-hac-suc) question answer.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you have a `SearchRestriction`, Search Restriction is a set of rules which is applied on Flexible Search Query in order to limit the search results or to filter search results based on specific conditions.

You can see `SearchRestrictions` in Backoffice -> System -> Personalization, find the related one that adds `session.currentCountry` to your flexible search and either disable it or use `impersonationService` to execute your query inside a context with a site.

Hope this helps